# How to suppress any output from child process created with fork / exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, exec, fork

From within a test case (ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest) i have to fire up a rails server instance.

This is the code that starts the rails server:

```
@@rails_server_proc = fork do
  Signal.trap("QUIT") { puts "Killing rails server"; exit }
  $stdout = nil
  exec("rails s -e test --port #{@@port}", [:out, :err] => "/dev/null")
end
Process.detach(@@rails_server_proc)
```

That works fine, but I couldn't find a way to suppress the rails server's STDOUT.

The `[:out, :err] => "/dev/null"` has no effect, I am still getting the server output in my test output like this:

```
Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in test on http://0.0.0.0:3002
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
exec("rails s -e test --port #{@@port} >/dev/null 2>&1")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that: No effect, still getting the output.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know.  At first I thought you might be on Windows where it would be `nul` instead of `/dev/null`.